# return new state, don't mutate it. Am i doing it right way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am rendering a `tabList`, `onclick` of any tab it will be highlighted. I am achieving this by checking a `selected` attribute.
Everytime a tab is clicked I am changing `selected` to `true/false` in my `reducer`.

`myTabsReducer` should not mutate but return a new array.

Am I doing it right way? As per documentation We should not **mutate state** (should not alter state). In my case I'm altering my `reducer`. Is it Ok to do it or is there any other way to achieve it?

```
export const myTabsReducer = (id) => {
      return [
        {
            id: 1,
            name:"My Tab 1",
            selected: id==1?true:false
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name:"My Tab 2",
            selected: id==2?true:false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name:"My Tab 3",
            selected: id==3?true:false
          }
      ]
    }

const myActiveTabReducer = (state = {}, action) => {  
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_PLAN_TAB:
      return action.payload
    default:
      return 1;
  }
}

const allReducers = (state = {}, action) => {
    return {
      allTabs: myTabsReducer(myActiveTabReducer(state, action)),
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like code smell to me.

Comment: Sorry @vijayst, I did not get you. Do you have any suggestion for this piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

It would be much better to have your state in this way:

```
const initialState = {
  tabs: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Tab 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Tab 2' }
  ],
  selectedTab: 1
}
```

so that your reducer changes only the selectedTab property on "SELECT_PLAN_TAB":

```
const activeTabReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_PLAN_TAB:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedTab: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then, if you need the tabs array with the selected property for each tab, I would use a selector: see http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

Comment: Exactly. was going to recommend this myself but you already did it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mutating the array. Every time reducer is called you generate a new array.

```
const foo1 = allReducers({}, {type:' SELECT_PLAN_TAB', payload: 1})
const foo2 = allReducers({}, {type:' SELECT_PLAN_TAB', payload: 1})

console.log(foo1.allTabs === foo2.allTabs) // false
```

You should be careful, because this function will always return new instance even if input stays the same. This means that shallow equality check will fail and depending on how you consume this store, your component will always re-render.